# Removing Report Filter, Column Labels, Row Labels & Value Fields from Pivot

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

In my active sheet I want to remove all fields in every pivot table contained in the active sheet.

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Hide_Fields()
For Each Pvt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    For Each PvtFld In Pvt.PivotFields
      PvtFld.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next PvtFld
Next Pvt
End Sub
```

It removes all the fields except for the value field. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PivotFields` collection seems to exclude items that you can still reference. E.g. these won't error in the immediate window:

```
? ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of c")
? ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Values")
```

*(note that my pivot has a column named `c`)*

But they won't output per your code:

```
For Each fld In pvt.PivotFields
    Debug.Print fld.Name
Next fld
```

It's not clear why these aren't exposed when enumerating the collection.

However, you can refer directly to sub-collections of `PivotFields` such as `RowFields`, `ColumnFields`, `PageFields` and `DataFields`. By doing so, you can achieve your objective:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    HideFields ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
End Sub

Sub HideFields(pvt As PivotTable)
    Dim fld As Object
    'rows
    For Each fld In pvt.RowFields
        Debug.Print fld.Name
        fld.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next fld
    'columns
    For Each fld In pvt.ColumnFields
        Debug.Print fld.Name
        fld.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next fld
    'pages
    For Each fld In pvt.PageFields
        Debug.Print fld.Name
        fld.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next fld
    'data
    For Each fld In pvt.DataFields
        Debug.Print fld.Name
        fld.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next fld
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks so much!